# Template does not exist

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django. I made a folder named templates in my project and "base.html" inside it, it works fine. But when I make new folder inside templates welcome and then "home.html" and I write some lines of code in my views.py file as

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def hello(request):
    return render_to_response('welcome/home.html')
```

and settings.py includes

```
# Django settings for Telecom project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

import os
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)


MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mysql',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'UTC'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')


# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/admin/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'b9_hyqe*b&ra_&wlm5a9xas_ag#5mjv-dy=to%hdk_u-#xvn*l'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (       
                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),

)

print PROJECT_DIR
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Telecom.urls'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'welcome',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

but the error shows

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/
/welcome/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/hello/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
/welcome/home.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\django\template\loader.py in find_template, line 131
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\Bishnu\\BE\\4th year\\8th semester\\Major Project II\\Working\\Workspace\\Telecom',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg',
 'D:\\Bishnu\\BE\\4th year\\8th semester\\Major Project II\\Working\\Workspace\\Telecom',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip']
Server time:    Tue, 18 Jun 2013 17:09:07 +0545
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Any reason to use Django development version? This hasn't been released yet and may contain bugs. Have you tried the latest stable 1.5? It seems to try to load your template at the root (`/`) instead of the base paths. Are you sure your `PROJECT_DIR` is correct and pointing to the absolute path? Try `print PROJECT_DIR` in `settings.py` to find out the contents. And what have you set as `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` ?

Comment: Show the tree directory, where your "welcome/home.html" template are. Write your settings.py file too.

Comment: PROJECT_DIR displays D:\Bishnu\BE\4th year\8th semester\Major Project II\Working\Workspace\Telecom\Telecom

Comment: I have included settings.py in my question

Comment: I think you have to specify the template folder (if it's not the default) somewhere in order for Django to find it. Check out Django's doc on templating.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error may arises due to the incorrect template directories
Try some change on `settings.py` as below

```
import os.path
Temp_Path = os.path.realpath('.')
...
STATIC_ROOT = ''    
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    Temp_Path +"/template"
)
```

Then put all your template inside template folder and css/javascript file in static folder which is located inside your application folder. Hope this will solve your problem.

[My suggestion don't put template folder inside application folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)

> Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and
>   if you had a template with the same name in a different application,
>   Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able
>   to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this
>   is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside
>   another directory named for the application itself.

Answer (score 25):

For Django 1.8 or above
you need to open the `settings.py` file and add the template path in the `DIRS` key of `TEMPLATES` list as a list of string.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['Secondjango/Secondjango/templates/welcome'],  # <<<<<<<<Here
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

In your settings.py file replace

```
 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (       
                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),

)
```

with

```
 
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (       
                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates/welcome')

)
```

Then, in your code, just call **render_to_response("home.html")**

 
That should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

For Django 2.0, I edited the value DIRS of TEMPLATES in setting file to the entry directory of the project:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['.'], # here set DIRS to project's entry directory
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

and the problem solved on both Mac and Windows systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:
in settigns.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),)


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Django 1.8 or above just Add the following in TEMPLATES DIR variable list in settings file**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

This property points to template directory `'DIRS': ['templates'],`

Comment: ImportError at /race/
templates doesn't look like a module path

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have added your new application in the settings.py file under INSTALLED_APPS

Django compiles all the 'templates' folder from all the applications inside your project into a single 'templates' folder.

Please remember to create separate directory inside your applications 'template' folder to make it easier for the Django framework to find the template you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

suppose that you hace a django project "my_project", and the application "app_1" and "app_2"

```
my_project
    -- my_project  
    -- manage.py
    welcome
        -- __init__.py
        templates               
            -- home.html
        -- models.py
        -- views.py

    app_1
        -- __init__.py
        templates
            welcome
                -- home.html
        -- models.py
        -- views.py
    app_2
        templates
            a_subfolder
               -- home.html
        -- __init__.py
        -- models.py
        -- views.py
```

now, if you have some settings like.

```
#...
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)
#...

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'app_2', 
    'app_1',
    'welcome',
    #...
)

#...
```

django will do that:
When you call `render_to_response('welcome/home.html')` (I think that some params are missing), django will look at "home.html" file in some some "welcome" folder in ALL aplications (in this case "app_1" and "app_2") that have a "templates" folder. (that is a convention)

**EDIT**

I have added you "welcome" app.

You have to call the method without app name `render_to_response('home.html')`

Comment: I have done already what you have answered and welcome is the only app that I have created which I have included already. But not getting the solution.

Comment: Have you the "templates" folder in "welcome" app? Did you call `render_to_response('home.html')` ?

Comment: I have made the folder templates just inside my main project folder Telecom not inside any app, at the same location where the manage.py locates. I have done in eclipse.

Comment: Put the template folder inside the "welcome" app. what version of django are you? (My English is not so good, I know)

Comment: Please try this and let me know if it is working or not. You add templates/welcome inside your settings->TEMPLATE_DIRS. Then inside your view also write this render_to_response('welcome/home.html').

Comment: I have installed 1.6 version of django.(My English is not good too so I understand what you mean). I think making different templates folder for each app is not a good practice rather making different folder(similar to app name) inside the template is good so I have made the folder templates just inside the project folder. I need another better answer ?

Comment: The reason: **write reusable apps**

Comment: @sandeep is on the right track; however, in your code, call *render_to_response("home.html")* ; that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is any include tag in "hello.html" which has been given filepath that does not exist. The error raised comes up the same :-

TemplateDoesNotExist at /hello/
/welcome/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Add template directory to your *TEMPLATES*  in your project `settings.py` by `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`

So the final TEMPLATES should be something like the following

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

-> Make sure your templates folder should be in root folder not in app folder
-> then goto your setting.py file and look for `TEMPLATES = [ 'DIRS': ]` 
-> in DIRS put the path of your template folder like this `'DIRS':[r'path']`

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be if the name of the folder in your app is `template` and not `templates`.  Note **'s'** in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings.py file must be :

'DIRS': ["templates"]

Your templates folder must be under your main project name :

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM3Ml.png)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was Install 'rest_framework' as one of the apps.

Comment: And How to do that ?. Please put it on your answer

Answer (score -3):

Have you created the file `__init__.py` inside your `welcome` folder?

Comment: yes. without this file any template inside the folder will not be accessible.

Comment: Yes, i know, just write the undescores :)

Comment: This comment is wrong and misleading. `__init__.py` is only relevent for Python packages (ie. containing `.py` files), not Django template dirs.